# How do I dismiss OSX Character Picker Palette from code

Tags: swift, macos, nswindow

I can present the Character Picker Palette (emoji) with:

```
NSApplication.shared.orderFrontCharacterPalette(self)
```

But I can't find any way to dismiss the Character Picker Palette from code when I'd like to.

I have tried iterating through all open windows, and closing all but the main window like this, but although my print statement reports 2 other windows, it does not close the character picker palette :

```
    let openwindows = NSApplication.shared.windows
    for win in openwindows {
        if win == self.view.window {
            print("Found and ruled out the main window") // successfull
        }else{
            print(win.className)
            // finds two other windows and prints
            // _NSCandidateBarCorrectionPanel
            // NSCorrectionSubPanel
            //
            win.close() // Has no effect
            // win.orderOut(self) // Has no effect
            // win.performClose(nil) // sounds system beep
        }
    }
```

Comment: The character picker is a window of the CharacterPalette app (/System/Library/Input Methods/).

Comment: you got any solution for this issue? @gary